# Is Change Detection in Angular the only mechanism thatr re-renders the DOM?

Tags: angular, html-rendering, angular-changedetection

I did a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/github/AndreaDiCioccio/ChangeDetectionStrategy-Default-Demo1) to run tests on the default change detection in angular.
The tests showed that the DOM is updated with the new values (changed by clicking) even if the onChange () method is not executed. We know that it only runs when the CD detects changes.

This is the test: if you click on the 'Change Name 1' button, the CD does not detect the changes (for reasons that I am not explaining now) but the DOM is updated anyway with the new values both in the parent component and in the child.

So I wonder, who is in charge of rendering the DOM, instead of the CD when it does not detect changes? Why is the DOM updated even if the CD does not detect changes?

parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <h1>Default Change Detection Demo1</h1>
        <h3>name: {{person.name}}</h3>
        <button (click)="changeName1()">Chanage Name 1</button>
        <button (click)="changeName2()">Chanage Name 2</button>
        <app-child [person]="person"></app-child>
    `
})

export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {

    person = {
        name: 'Paperino'
    }

    //it is never called in the root component because it is used only for @Input properties
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){

        console.log('appComponent ->> change detection')

    }

    changeName1(){
        this.person.name = 'Gastone'
    }

    changeName2(){
        this.person = {
            name: 'Zio Paperone'
        }
    }

}
```

child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `
        <h2>Child Component</h2>
        <h3>name: {{person.name}}</h3>
    `
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {

@Input() person

    //it is called whenever the input properties change their value(reference)
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){

        console.log('childComponent ->> change detection')
        
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you claim "_if you click on the 'Change Name 1' button, the CD does not detect the changes_"? For all I can see, you aren't controlling the change detection.

Comment: onChange() is called when CD detects change, there is not log of onChange()

Answer (score 0):

Changedetection is run when clicking on both buttons because CD runs on a click event.
I updated the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-knfcjw which shows when changedetection is actually runs.

button 1: changedetection runs, ngOnchanges is not triggered because you do not provide a new reference
button 2: changedetection runs, ngOnchanges is triggered because you provide a new reference

Comment: I agree, CD is run on events, interval or timeout etc...I never said otherwise, the question is who re-render the DOM if CD donesen't detect change? CD re-renders the DOM just if it detect changes.

Comment: Why do you think that changedetection is not run in your example?

Comment: I do NOT say that the CD is not performed, I am aware that the CD is performed! but it does not detect changes, since onChange () does not log ... and since it does not detect changes, it does not render the DOM again, who does it in its place?

Comment: I looked at your demo well, I thought about it and now I understand what you mean, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` hook has nothing to do with the change detection. It is triggered when the reference to the `@Input` variables are adjusted.

In the `changeName1()` function, the input variable isn't rewritten, but the underlying object reference points to the same object. So the change detection **is run** when the `this.person.name` is assigned a new value.

In the `changeName2()` function, the input variable is rewritten. So the change detection **is run** and the `ngOnChanges` is triggered.

To really see this in action, set the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush` instead of `Default` in the child component. With `OnPush` strategy, change detection will re-render the component only when the `@Input` variables are adjusted. So `changeName1()` function wouldn't change the child component.

So in your code, the change detection **IS RUN** in both the cases.

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ough9c).

Comment: onChange() in invoked immediately after CD has encountered at least one change in the data.I agree when u say that it takes care of @Input. I see your example and I have even more confused ideas, but taking my demo as a reference, who calls the DOM's re-rendering if the CD doesn't?

Comment: please be patience :-D the official documentation is fragmented and difficult to consult. What you write makes me understand that the CD re-renders the DOM even if it does not find changes in the data, is it so?

Comment: That is more or less correct. Only difference is CD does find changes in the data, and re-renders the template. But it doesn't trigger the `ngOnChanges()` hook because the actual reference to the `@Input()` object hasn't changed. It is better _not_ to assert that the CD isn't triggered if the `ngOnChanges()` isn't called. The CD is indeed triggered, but the `ngOnChanges()` isn't called.

Comment: You can however assert that the CD isn't re-rendering the DOM in my adjusted Stackblitz. There the `OnPush` strategy for CD is used. With the `OnPush` strategy, the DOM is re-rendered only when the reference to the `@Input()` variable is changed. So in other words, the CD re-renders the DOM only when the `ngOnChanges()` hook is called.

Comment: I previously believed that the CD would only re-render if it found changes but I never thought it wouldn't be called. It is almost all clear, I will do further tests with onPush. But there remains a veil of mystery about the re-rendering of the DOM in the parent component. Since the CD takes care of Input and there are no Inputs in the parent component, so the CD is excluded, who will re-render the DOM of the parent component when datas changes? Thanks for patience ad time

Comment: You're welcome :). Each component has it's own change detector. So the app component is re-rendered every time it's _own_ member variable `person` is modified. It is important to understand that change detector re-renders not only when the `@Input` variables change, but whenever _any_ of the member variable is modifed.

Comment: ok, now there are, you have been very exhaustive. I will reread the documentation and do some tests. I will inform you if I have any further doubts. Thanks so much!